# OpenCV Coordinates of matching template

Tags: java, opencv, coordinate-systems, template-matching

I am currently trying to program a template matcher from the openCV tutorial using these images:
[image]
[image]

I successfully get the match, however I don't need the visualization of drawing a rectangle like

```
 Imgproc.rectangle(img, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(),
            matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
```

More importantly I wan't to get the coordinates of the matching template.

```
        System.out.println(String.format("X: %s \nY: %s" , matchLoc.x, matchLoc.y)); 
       -> X: 259.0  Y: 349.0
```

How can I retrieve the coordinates of every Point creating the resulting rectangle or maybe there is already a method for that?

Comment: sorry, you DON'T want the rectangle?  you can make them yourself, if that's what you're asking

Comment: well I want to have the coordinates of the rectangle not the visualization @frank